# confusion on UIView, its class and UIViewController - xcode iOS objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

- In storyboard, I dragged out UIView onto my ViewController.
- Assign UIView to custom class "myUIView" (which will be myUIView.h and myUIView.m)
- Set up ViewController like this:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScheduleViewingVC : UIViewController

//for the dragged-out UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myUIViewOutlet; 

//to do some drawings on myUIViewOutlet
@property (strong, nonatomic) myUIView *myUIViewClass; 

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //resize my UIView into a square
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGRect squareFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenWidth);
    _myUIViewOutlet = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:squareFrame];
}
@end
```

If I run this project,

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {}
```

inside **myUIViewClass.m** runs automatically since.. it's linked to myUIViewOutlet.

Now, I need send some data to **myUIViewClass** linked to **myUIViewOutlet** from **ViewController**.

It doesn't seem right to send data to myUIViewOutlet from ViewController..
How can I make this work correctly? Should I send data to **myUIViewClass**?

Can anyone make this clear for me? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by myUIViewClass linked to myUIViewOutlet?You think they are some object?

Comment: shouldn't the UIView (the little frame) have to have its own class to do some methods to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending data to **myUIViewClass** will not be right. Instead you can implement some Protocol (Delegate, DataSource kind) of mechanism.

What you can do is as follows:

1. Define some Custom Protocol say **myUIViewProtocol** in your myUIView class.
2. Define a delegate and methods you need.
3. Let your ViewController conform to this protocol and override this methods.

This approach is same as 
**UITableView**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've looked up and found that i can send from CHILD -> PARENT via protocol.. can I do that in both directions at the same time?